# Raster Layers in JS Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, logic

I need your help for a little paint application with layers.
I'd like my program to handle different layers, but not using more than one canvas or using external libraries, in order to learn more about how this whole canvas thing works.
I thought about memorizing every data in arrays located in different layers objects and than print them on the canvas from the lowest to the highest. The problem is that i'd like to paint by hand, not just with circles and squares. If I'll memorize everything I draw by hand, then it will be very slow (already tried).
Thank you all for the help!

Comment: So, what is your specific programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly apply an informal z-index using just one canvas.

And you have determined one proper way to do that:

- Serialize ("remember") all the drawing commands & arguments.
- clear the canvas.
- redraw all polylines on each layer in proper order.

Then you can replay those saved commands. The display will occur very quickly.

**Here is a version of your `Layer.draw` method** which has been refactored for better performance:

```
// draw() will define & stroke all polylines on this layer
// The 1st point in each polyline contains that line's styling
Layer.prototype.draw = function( ctx ) {

    // just return if there's no points to draw
    if(this.points.length<2){return;}

    // cache an often used array
    var pts=this.points;

    // index for points
    var i=0;

    // process all points in the
    while(i<pts.length){

        // cache the often used first point in a new polyline
        var p=pts[i];

        // set styles for this polyline 
        ctx.lineWidth = p.lineWidth;
        ctx.lineJoin = p.lineJoin;
        ctx.lineCap = p.lineCap;
        ctx.strokeStyle = p.strokeStyle;

        // begin this polyline path
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        i++;

        // define all segment points on this polyline
        while( i<pts.length && pts[i].lineWidth==undefined ) {
            ctx.lineTo( pts[i].x , pts[i].y );
            i++;
        }

        // stroke this polyline
        ctx.stroke();

    } // end while(i<pts.length)
}
```

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
Point = function( x , y ) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Point.prototype.invert = function() {
  var t = this.x;
  this.x = this.y;
  this.y = t;
}

Layer = function() {
  this.points = [];
}

Layer.prototype.draw = function( ctx ) {

  // just return if there's no points to draw
  if(this.points.length<2){return;}

  // cache an often used array
  var pts=this.points;

  // index for points
  var i=0;

  // process all points in the
  while(i<pts.length){

    // cache the often used first point in a new polyline
    var p=pts[i];

    // set styles for this polyline 
    ctx.lineWidth = p.lineWidth;
    ctx.lineJoin = p.lineJoin;
    ctx.lineCap = p.lineCap;
    ctx.strokeStyle = p.strokeStyle;

    // begin this polyline path
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
    i++;

    // define all segment points on this polyline
    while( i<pts.length && pts[i].lineWidth==undefined ) {
      ctx.lineTo( pts[i].x , pts[i].y );
      i++;
    }

    // stroke this polyline
    ctx.stroke();

  } // end while(i<pts.length)
}

ExtendedPoint = function( x , y , style ) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.lineWidth = style.lineWidth;
  this.lineJoin = style.lineJoin;
  this.lineCap = style.lineCap;
  this.strokeStyle = style.strokeStyle;
}

function startLine( e ) {

  var x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  var y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

  var p = new ExtendedPoint( x , y , {
    lineWidth: 5,
    lineJoin: "round",
    lineCap: "round",
    // testing only: make each new polyline a different color
    // strokeStyle: "black"
    strokeStyle: randomColor(),
  });
  selectedLayer.points.push(p);

  isDrawing = true;
}

function continueLine( e ) {

  if (isDrawing == true) {
    var x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

    var p = new Point( x , y );
    selectedLayer.points.push( p );
  }
}

function endLine() {

  isDrawing = false;
}

function redraw() {
  context.clearRect( 0, 0, 400, 400 );
  for ( var i = 0 ; i < layers.length ; i++ ) {
    layers[i].draw( context );
  }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("cvs");

canvas.setAttribute("width" , 400);
canvas.setAttribute("height", 400);

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var layers = [];
layers.push( new Layer() );
var selectedLayer = layers[0];

var isDrawing = false;

canvas.addEventListener( "mousedown" , startLine );
canvas.addEventListener( "mousemove" , continueLine );
canvas.addEventListener( "mousemove" , redraw );
canvas.addEventListener( "mouseup" , endLine );



// testing only: make each polyline a different color
function randomColor(){ 
  return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Drag to draw layered lines</h4>
<canvas id="cvs" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I made it before, here it is a fiddle (just created it) https://jsfiddle.net/drago96/4gq011yx/ That's why i said that was slow, maybe it's my fault or i didn't express my thoughts very well... (sorry for the language, i'm not english)

Comment: Thanks really much for this, it works really well! I didn't thought that caching the points would make it so fast! (probably it's just the stroke function that is run just a few times). I had thought also of using three canvas (one for the layers that are on the top of the selected one, one for the painting on the selected layer and one for the layer behind). Than i'll save all layers as images that are than drawn using the drawImage() method. When i'm done programming this i'll put here a fiddle of this version too. Thanks a lot! Bye!

Comment: Finished the other idea. here it is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/drago96/4gq011yx/3/